# I'm getting an InvalidArgumentError because an index is apparently out of range. Why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use Keras-BERT to parse the SQuAD v1.1 dataset, but I don't understand this error, because the input shapes to Keras-BERT are correct:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 answers_network.fit(test_generator)
>
> 8 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py
> in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
> 58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
> ---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
> 61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> 62     if name is not None:
>
> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) Invalid argument:
> indices[1,0] = 101 is not in [0, 2)    [[node
> model_2/model_1/Embedding-Segment/embedding_lookup (defined at
> :1) ]]
> [[model_2/model_1_1/Embedding-Token/embedding_lookup/_22]]   (1)
> Invalid argument:  indices[1,0] = 101 is not in [0, 2)     [[node
> model_2/model_1/Embedding-Segment/embedding_lookup (defined at
> :1) ]] 0 successful operations. 0
> derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_64701]
>
> Errors may have originated from an input operation. Input Source
> operations connected to node
> model_2/model_1/Embedding-Segment/embedding_lookup:
> model_2/model_1/Embedding-Segment/embedding_lookup/41898 (defined at
> /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)
>
> Input Source operations connected to node
> model_2/model_1/Embedding-Segment/embedding_lookup:
> model_2/model_1/Embedding-Segment/embedding_lookup/41898 (defined at
> /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)
>
> Function call stack: train_function -> train_function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

# TF_KERAS must be added to environment variables in order to use TPU
os.environ['TF_KERAS'] = '1'
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
#import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding,Dropout,Lambda,Dense,Input,InputLayer,LSTM,Concatenate,Flatten,Add,Reshape,GlobalAveragePooling1D,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import sys
assert sys.version_info[0] >= 3
#from keras.backend import slice
print(tf.VERSION)
print(tf.keras.__version__)
print("Modules loaded!")

# @title Environment
pretrained_path = 'uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12'
config_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'bert_config.json')
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'bert_model.ckpt')
vocab_path = os.path.join(pretrained_path, 'vocab.txt')
# Use TF_Keras
os.environ["TF_KERAS"] = "1"

# @title Load Basic Model
import codecs
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint

token_dict = {}
with codecs.open(vocab_path, 'r', 'utf8') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        token = line.strip()
        token_dict[token] = len(token_dict)

model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path)

#@title Create tokenization stuff.
from keras_bert import Tokenizer

tokenizer = Tokenizer(token_dict)
def tokenize(text,max_len):
  tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  return tokenizer.encode(first=text,max_len=max_len)
def tokenize_array(texts,max_len=512):
  indices = np.zeros((texts.shape[0],max_len))
  segments = np.zeros((texts.shape[0],max_len))
  for i in range(texts.shape[0]):
    tokens = tokenize(texts[i],max_len)
    indices[i] = tokens[0]
    segments[i] = tokens[1]
  #print(indices.shape)
  #print(segments.shape)
  return np.stack([segments,indices],axis=1)

#@ Generate tokenized inputs and one-hot-encoded outputs.
def X_Y_generator(dataset,batch_size=10,max_int=-1):
  while True:
    try:
      dataset_batch = dataset.sample(n=batch_size)
      questions = dataset_batch["question"]
      context = dataset_batch["paragraph_context"]
      questions_tokenized = tokenize_array(questions.values)
      #print("questions tokenized", questions_tokenized.shape)
      context_tokenized = tokenize_array(context.values)
      #print("contexts tokenized", context_tokenized.shape)
      X = np.stack([questions_tokenized,context_tokenized],axis=1)
      # We need to consider the full range of possible values.
      if (max_int == -1):
        max_int = pd.concat((trainingData["answer_start"],devData["answer_start"])).max()
      Y = np.array([one_hot_int(i,max_int) for i in dataset_batch["answer_start"]])
      yield (X,Y)
    except Exception as e:
      print("Unhandled exception in X_Y_generator: ",e)
      raise

test_strings = ["She sells sea shells by the seashore.","Little Miss Muppet sat on her tuppet, eating her curds and whey."]
test_questions = ["Where does she sell seashells?","What did Little Miss Muppet eat?"]
test_indices = [test_strings[0].index("by the seashore."),test_strings[1].index("her curds and whey")]
test_dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"paragraph_context":test_strings,
                               "question":test_questions,
                               "answer_start":test_indices})
test_generator = X_Y_generator(test_dataFrame,batch_size=2)
test_generated = test_generator.__next__()

**Main network**
input_layer = Input(shape=(2,2,512,))
print("input layer: ",input_layer.shape)
questions_input_layer = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0])(input_layer)
context_input_layer = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1])(input_layer)
print("questions input layer: ",questions_input_layer.shape)
print("context input layer: ",context_input_layer.shape)
questions_indices_layer = Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast(x[:,0],tf.float64))(questions_input_layer)
print("questions indices layer: ",questions_indices_layer.shape)
questions_segments_layer = Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast(x[:,1],tf.float64))(questions_input_layer)
print("questions segments layer: ",questions_segments_layer.shape)
context_indices_layer = Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast(x[:,0],tf.float64))(context_input_layer)
context_segments_layer = Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast(x[:,1],tf.float64))(context_input_layer)
questions_bert_layer = model([questions_indices_layer,questions_segments_layer])
print("Questions bert layer loaded.")
context_bert_layer = model([context_indices_layer,context_segments_layer])
print("Context bert layer loaded.")
questions_bert_layer.trainable = False
context_bert_layer.trainable = False
concat = Add()([questions_bert_layer,context_bert_layer])
bert_flatten = Flatten()(concat)
bert_dense = Dense(512,activation="softmax")(bert_flatten)
answers_network_output = Dense(3127,activation="softmax")(bert_dense)
#answers_network = Model(inputs=[input_layer],outputs=[questions_bert_layer,context_bert_layer])
answers_network = Model(inputs=[input_layer],outputs=[answers_network_output])

answers_network.compile("adam","categorical_crossentropy",metrics=[f1])

answers_network.fit(test_generator)
```